# Check 2 values in 2 columns in a join query

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

I have two tables :

**prd_brand**

- brand_id
- name

**catalog_product_entity_int**

- attribute_id
- rowid
- value

I joined this two tables like follows :

```
SELECT main_table.* 
FROM prd_brand AS main_table 
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_int 
ON main_table.brand_id=catalog_product_entity_int.value 
group by brand_id 
order by name asc
```

What I want to do now is to check in `catalog_product_entity_int` table if the `attribute_id` **97** has a `value` **1**. If it has a value other than 1 then do not take it.

**prd_brand**

```
brand_id    |   name
26          |   Nivea
44          |   Ducray
```

**catalog_product_entity_int**

```
attribute_id    |   rowid   |   value 
198             |   174     |   26 
97              |   174     |   1
788             |   174     |   4
198             |   210     |   44
97              |   210     |   0
```

Nivea (ID 26) exists in the `catalog_product_entity_int` table, its `rowid` is 174, this `rowid` has a value 1 in the `attribute_id` 97 => we take it.

Ducray (ID 44) exists in the `catalog_product_entity_int` table, its `rowid` is 210, this `rowid` has a value 0 in the `attribute_id` 97 => we DO NOT take it.

Comment: Post some sample data and your expected result.

Comment: 1) query with `select *` and `group by` is wrong. 2) sample data with expected output would be helpful

Comment: @Forward : please see edited post with example

Comment: @OtoShavadze : please see edited post with example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I figure it out with [**`group_concat`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and [**`find_in_set`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
select distinct a.*
from prd_brand a
join (
    select
        group_concat(attribute_id order by attribute_id) attrs, 
        group_concat(`value` order by attribute_id) vals
    from catalog_product_entity_int
    group by `rowid`
) b
on find_in_set(a.brand_id, b.vals)
and find_in_set('97', b.attrs) > 0
and find_in_set('1', b.vals);
```

See [**demo**](http://rextester.com/BKO26892) here.

Or `join` solution with subquery:

```
select distinct a.*
from prd_brand a
join catalog_product_entity_int b1
on a.brand_id = b1.`value`
and exists (
    select 1
    from catalog_product_entity_int b2
    where b1.rowid = b2.rowid
    and b2.`value` = 1
    and b2.`attribute_id` = 97
)
```

also a [**demo**](http://rextester.com/WCYU40407) here.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, the demos and the two possible solutions ! I selected your second one.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way

```
select prd_brand.* from prd_brand
inner join
(
    select distinct value from catalog_product_entity_int
    where 
    rowid in (select rowid from catalog_product_entity_int where attribute_id = 97 and value = 1)
)t
on prd_brand.brand_id = t.value
```

Comment: I would like to accept your answer as it frankly is the most clear one. And of course that it works ! Thank you.